# ETW - Best Fix/Class-Library for Messy Interface?

Tags: logging, etw

By ETW I mean "Event Tracing for Windows".

According to my experimenting one virtue is that while by-design it occasionally fails to record events in Very-Busy conditions it otherwise Just Works, as you might expect from a Kernel feature.  ETW is the only game in town if you want per-processor-buffering to avoid cache-vs-multi-thread-logging issues, since as I understand it "Only the Kernel Knows" where your threads are really running at any given instant, especially if you don't assign affinity etc.

Yet the interface is messy, and gets even worse if you consider the Microsoft-recommended approach relative to EventWrite().
What's the best available effort at streamlining the programmer's access to this powerful Kernel Subsystem ?  I am interested in a C++ interface, but others viewing this question will want to know about the other languages too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for an ease-of-use C/C++ wrapper on top of ETW, the only thing that comes close is WPP. You might hit limitations in WPP if you get too advanced. Watch out for Microsoft PDC in October for something helpful ;)

Comment: I had briefly looked at WPP but it seemed mainly aimed at Device-Driver-Writers.  Thanks for the tip about PDC.

Comment: WPP is not just for Device Driver writers, it can be used in any native app. WPP is easy to start using, but you can end up in dead-ends. ETW is getting used heavily internally at MS.